# Optimizing a slow query to better use indexing

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have a query that looks like the following:

```
SELECT time_stop, some_count
        FROM foo
        WHERE user_id = 1
        AND time_start >= '2016-07-27 00:00:00'
        AND time_stop <= '2016-07-27 23:59:59' 
        AND some_count = ( SELECT MAX(some_count) 
          FROM foo
          WHERE user_id = 1
          AND tm_start >= '2016-07-27 00:00:00'
          AND tm_stop <= '2016-07-27 23:59:59'
       );
```

The table schema looks something like this:

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time_start` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_stop` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `some_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),,
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `time_start` (`time_start`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=418005923 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

EXPLAIN output looks like the following:

```
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+------+------------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table          | partitions | type | possible_keys      | key     | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+------+------------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | foo            | NULL       | ref  | user_id,time_start | user_id | 4       | const | 931364 |     1.67 | Using where |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | foo            | NULL       | ref  | user_id,time_start | user_id | 4       | const | 931364 |    16.66 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+------+------------------+---------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
```

I'm using MySQL 5.7.11.

I think the major problem I'm having is there's very little cardinality in the indexed keys here. The query is attempting to get the largest value of `some_count` for a given date range. It also wants the exact `datetime` that the max value was met. This could return multiple rows, which returns to the little cardinality problem.

I'm not sure if I could re-write the query to better work with the existing indexes, I'm guessing I could though.

Comment: First put an index on time_stop and see how that helps! How long does it take before and after?

Comment: should it be a separate index? or should it be part of the `time_start` index?

Comment: Separate index I think. Wouldn't be too difficult to experiment with both though. Both in the sense of 1 separate and also both together. Is the table frequently updated?

Comment: Very frequently, tons of writes happening to it.

Comment: Have you actually apllied a single non compound index to time_stop? Could you do that and report back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query seems to be simply this:

```
SELECT time_stop, some_count
    FROM foo
    WHERE user_id = 1
    AND time_start >= '2016-07-27 00:00:00'
    AND time_stop <= '2016-07-27 23:59:59'
 ORDER BY some_count DESC LIMIT 1;
```

You need an index on (user_id,time_start) -- in that order -- and, assuming start is always earlier than stop, adding the seemingly-unnecessary `AND time_start <= '2016-07-27 23:59:59'` will allow the database to avoid even considering rows with time_start values later.

Also adding time_stop to the same index will not help you, for the same reason that the telephone directory won't help you find all people with first names beginning with the letter L.  Adding some_count to the index also won't help, for the same reason.  In a multi-column index, the values in column B are sorted within identical groups of column A (hence the telephone directory reference). The values in column C are sorted within identical groups of B, etc... so if A is an equality comparison, and B is a range, as in your query, those are easy to pinpoint... but the values of C appear random.  For C to be usable in an index, B needs also to be an equality comparison, which it is not, in your case.

However, if these are the only columns you're reading, then adding those columns to the index (to the right of user_id and time_start) could be useful for a different reason -- when a query uses an index that contains all the columns selected, it's a "covering index," and the entire result can be read directly from the index, instead of the main table, potentially giving a benefit that you have to weigh against the cost of maintaining larger indexes.

Comment: `AND time_start <= '2016-07-27 23:59:59' ` is this a typo (shoukd be time_stop)? Could you expand on why an index on time_stop is of no benefit? p.s. +1.

Comment: Your query return at most 1 row, the OP's query can return multiple rows

Comment: @Lennart you are correct.  I did make an assumption, perhaps unjustified, that OP was trying to accomplish what my query does, but doing it the hard way.  The rest of the answer is applicable to the original query as well.

Comment: @Vérace thanks.  Not a typo.  Adding this additional predicate prevents the server from considering any rows which start later than the stop time we query against, presumably a constraint on the data that the optimizer has no way of knowing.  Without adding this, it will have to evaluate every row where '2016-07-27 00:00:00' <= time_start <=  infinity because it has no intrinsic knowledge that only rows where  '2016-07-27 00:00:00' <= time_start <=  '2016-07-27 23:59:59' could possibly be wanted.  We can't get there with `WHERE time_start < time_start` because we need constants on both sides.

Comment: @Vérace think of a multicolumn index with (last_name,first_name,middle_name).  Values in the index are sorted by middle_name within each first_name, and by first_name within each last_name.  Unless last and first are known, the index can't pinpoint middle.  If we query last = Smith and first LIKE J% we have to scan through all the rows matched to find a specific middle name because from our perspective the middle names are not sorted -- they are sorted within each first, not helpful. If last = Smith and first = John then the middle names, from our perspective *are* sorted.  LIKE J% is a range.

Comment: ...and this is analogous to the query, here. Indexes work left to right.  When we look up user_id, we find all the time_start values for that user stored in perfect order.  But the time_stop values are sorted within each distinct time_start.  If we are looking for a range of time_start values, the sorting of time_stop is not in an order that is useful, because they are sorted within each distinct time_start -- not independently.  A separate index on (user_id,time_stop) would help but [index merge](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-merge-optimization.html) won't use it, iirc.

Comment: @Lennart is correct in that my query can return multiple rows. In the application side, I'd filter for the row that had the most current timestamp. This could be accomplished by changing `ORDER BY some_count DESC LIMIT 1` to `ORDER BY some_count DESC, some_count DESC LIMIT 1`.